# Where can I find current laptop temperature?

Tags: laptop, temperature, proc

I have a script which logs information about my Toshiba laptop, such as its current temperature, and sends that information to [Pachube](https://pachube.com/feeds/22344). Recently, I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.11 and the Kernel 3.0 series and my script stopped working.

The `temperature` file, which used to be in `/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/TZ01/temperature` now no longer exists. There is a relevant directory at `/proc/acpi/toshiba/` but its contents are as follows:

```
$ ls
fan  keys  lcd  version  video
$ cat *
running:                 0
force_on:                0
hotkey_ready:            0
hotkey:                  0x0000
brightness:              7
brightness_levels:       8
driver:                  0.19
proc_interface:          1
lcd_out:                 0
crt_out:                 0
tv_out:                  0
$
```

So, no temperature. Does anyone know a way to get this information? Is it still in `/proc/` somewhere?

Comment: I realise, btw there are other ways to do this, for example using the lm-sensors package (see my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952430/how-to-portably-parse-the-unicode-degree-symbol-with-regular-expressions)), but I'm really looking for a method which doesn't rely on external packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to find the temperature for my Toshiba laptop, expressed in 1/1000 of a degree Celsius, in _/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp_

`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp

51000`

and acpi -t returns:
*Thermal 0: ok, 51.0 degrees C*

My system only has a thermal_zone *0* but I suppose other systems may have more than one zone.